# How can I try Ubuntu without changing anything on my computer?

Tags: windows, mac

I've never used Linux before and I'm a little unsure.

Comment: Just a side-note... what is *this* question coming from someone with **1200+** reputation and more than 80 answers?!?!

Comment: Damn @wojox. You just made my day with this question :D

Comment: @MestreLion: Turtles. [It's turtles all the way down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo).

Comment: @Piskvor: amazing link! Im still amazed how could an answer like "The first thing you have to do is write tests, then you can worry about moving the turtle." was worth **289** votes. And still puzzled about this question here... is this some inside joke or something (worse)?

Comment: @MestreLion: What I meant to say was, "perhaps @wojox wanted to ask a deliberately simple and common question, so that it could become the canonical (pun not intended) go-to post for *this* specific question; just as @JSpolsky posted the question about, um, turtles". As for "turtles all the way down", that is quite well searchable ;)

Comment: @wojox: you are hilarious brother :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download the ISO from [Ubuntu.com](http://ubuntu.com) and follow the directions on the site.

Put the disc in your drive and boot up the computer. It will boot into the live environment. Live meaning it is running off the CD/DVD disk and RAM but not off your hard drive. It will not touch the hard drive at all.

You have to boot from the CD if it does not do this automatically. You may have to [press a certain key](http://www.mydigitallife.info/comprehensive-list-of-how-key-to-press-to-access-bios-for-various-oem-and-computer-systems/) to get to the boot menu while starting up. This depends on your computer but is usually F12 to bring up the boot menu and F1,F10, or Delete, to bring up the BIOS menu. You need to change the boot order of your computer to boot from the CD/DVD device first.  It should say what key to press on the boot screen. :) Have fun!

Alternatively [WUBI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) installs along side your main operating system and can then be accessed as an option from the start menu. It then runs in side windows, and can be uninstalled at any time later.

Comment: This sounds like everything I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can also install Ubuntu using Wubi (*windows installer*).

Live CD is good, but it's slow and uncomortable. If you want to try out everything, mount the CD image via **Daemon tools** while using windows, open the cd in explorer and look for wubi.exe program inside. It also might use autorun.
Run it and follow the instructions.

Later you can remove it just like any other Windows program: **uninstal.exe** file.

However, not everything will work well. For example you will have to write more passwords and the speed won't be as good as in normal install.

Answer (score 2):

Download [Ubuntu iso from Ubuntu site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download). Burn it into a CD. Then boot it and enter into Live CD mode to try ubuntu without causing any change to the existing system.

Other way without even burning the iso is [install virtual box and try it there](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox).

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) to virtually load Ubuntu os on your existing operating system,

you can run multiple OS simultaneously using virtualbox

Download Ubuntu VM and load in virtualbox
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox#1-overview

If you literally don't want to change anything on your computer and try Ubuntu
Go to AWS and get a Ubuntu EC2 instance
or go to any cloud provider and get a ubuntu instance

Comment: Mind that the performance will be far from a real install in a VM

Comment: If you do a full install, yes. On the other hand, performance of a Live CD booted from an ISO file in a VM is usually a lot better than using the physical CD, either in a VM or on the bare metal.

Answer (score 1):

using [live cd / live usb](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download).

and yeah you can run it on windows using [WUBI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the ubuntu cd.

If u have one or if u don't have then download the iso and write it to the cd or probably mount the iso or image file in a virtual drive using poweriso or something similar to that...i guess nowadays nero also mount images to a drive....

Then just simply run the program or cd or image extracted file.....then u will be guided automatically...

It is really simple .... it is like installing a windows software only.

Also u can run the live cd and use it without installing it in your system.

Hope