# How to install linux without affecting my original OS?

Tags: 12.04, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up a dual boot Windows  and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)

How can I install ubuntu linux 12.04 without affecting my original windows 7 OS? I just want to try using linux for a while before I share my hard drive with it. So please anyone let me know how to install linux without affecting my original OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/107538/54298

Comment: You can also boot the CD and try it without installing. You won;t get the full power of it, but it'll be fine to test for compatibility.

Comment: I am not sure but looks like it is similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/47955/how-can-i-try-ubuntu-without-changing-anything-on-my-computer

Answer (score 0):

do you know the dual boot option ?

Dual-Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu in Perfect Harmony
Windows 7 and Ubuntu, despite their opposing missions, can get along like best pals on a single computer. Here's how to set up a dual boot system that lets you enjoy the best of both worlds in perfect harmony.

By default, Windows 7 takes over your boot-up process and wants to be your only OS, and Linux treats Windows like a weekend hobby you keep in a shed somewhere on your hard drive. But I've been dual-booting Ubuntu and some version of Windows 7 for nearly a year, and I've learned a lot about inconveniences, annoyances, and file-sharing necessities, and now I'll walk you through how to set up your systems to achieve a peaceful union of your dual-boot OSes. (Both with Windows 7 already installed, and with a clean system ready for a new dual-OS existence.)

read more
http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony

more information now we are using 1204 .. there is no problem with my win 7 . and Ubuntu work perfectly good

how to dual-boot Ubuntu 12.04 with windows 7

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek2pdr4nGbc

and

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0W7XYAB4cLc

Answer (score 0):

You can install via WUBI. It installs like a regular application and you just need to download the installer from the Ubuntu website. FLOSS Weekly had a nice episode about WUBI.

Another option is to install it in a VM like with VirtualBox.